# Unity3D TestRunner hangs when using NSubstitute to mock a Monobehavior class

Tags: unit-testing, unity-game-engine, tdd, nsubstitute, test-runner

I have stripped my project down to the bare minimum to try to figure out this instance where Unity TestRunner hangs.  I have two Monobehaviors classes, GameController and TrialController.  I followed Jason Wiemann's excellent testing videos [Everything you need to know about Testing in Unity3D](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qCghhGLUa-Y) and [Testing Against Monobehaviors Using Mocks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r7VkbV0PRC8) to create an interface class, ITrialController, so that I can mock it for testing GameController.  The TestRunner hangs when I try to run TestWithGetNextSubstitute().  What am I doing wrong here?

============== GameCtrlTest.cs ===========================

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NSubstitute;
using NUnit.Framework;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.TestTools;

namespace Tests
{
    public class GameCtrlTest
    {
        GameController gameCtrl;

        [SetUp]
        public void TestSetup()
        {
            GameObject gameObject = new GameObject("GameController");
            gameCtrl = gameObject.AddComponent<GameController>();

            gameCtrl.trialCtrl = Substitute.For<ITrialController>();
            Assert.IsNotNull(gameCtrl.trialCtrl);


            Debug.Log("Test Setup() done");
        }


        [UnityTest]
        public IEnumerator TestWithGetNextSubstitute()
        {
            gameCtrl.trialCtrl.GetNextTrial().Returns( "test-1", "test-2", null);

            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

================== TrialController.cs ================================

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class TrialController : MonoBehaviour, ITrialController
{
    int trialsLeft = 2;
    public string GetNextTrial()
    {
        if (trialsLeft == 0)
            return null;
        else
        {
            string returnString = "trial--" + trialsLeft;
            trialsLeft--;
            return (returnString);
        }
    }

}
```

==================== ITrialController.cs =================

```
public interface ITrialController
{
    string GetNextTrial();
}
```

==================== GameController.cs ==================

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

// give Test Runner access to internal variables and methods
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("Tests")]


public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ITrialController trialCtrl { get; set; }


    //=================== MonoBehavior interface =======================
    void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log("gameController Awake()");
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("gameController Start()");

        if (trialCtrl != null)
            Debug.Log("trialCtrl already set");
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("calling FindObjectOfType(typeof(TrialController)");

            trialCtrl = (ITrialController)FindObjectOfType(typeof(TrialController));
            Debug.Assert(trialCtrl != null, "Problem finding TrialController");
        }
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    static bool levelInitialized = false;
    void Update()
    {
        if (!levelInitialized)
        {
            Debug.Log("gameController first Update()");

            levelInitialized = true;
        }

        string trialName = trialCtrl.GetNextTrial();
        while (trialName != null)
        {
            Debug.Log($"GameController got {trialName} from GetNextTrial");
            trialName = trialCtrl.GetNextTrial();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to move the GetNextTrial().Returns() call from the [UnityTest] to the [Setup].  This initially seems very limiting, but there is probably a way to move the parameter list **("test-1", "test-2", null)** into a variable so I can change it for different tests.

=============== GameCtrlTest.cs ===================================

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NSubstitute;
using NUnit.Framework;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.TestTools;

namespace Tests
{
    public class GameCtrlTest
    {
        GameController gameCtrl;

        [SetUp]
        public void TestSetup()
        {
            GameObject gameObject = new GameObject("GameController");
            gameCtrl = gameObject.AddComponent<GameController>();

            gameCtrl.trialCtrl = Substitute.For<ITrialController>();
            Assert.IsNotNull(gameCtrl.trialCtrl);
            gameCtrl.trialCtrl.GetNextTrial().Returns("test-1", "test-2", null);


            Debug.Log("Test Setup() done");
        }


        [UnityTest]
        public IEnumerator TestWithGetNextSubstitute()
        {

            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```